# go to line in logfile with multitail

Tags: tail

Using [mulitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/), I want to find a specific line in the logs, so I press the `/` key and type the string i want to search for. multitail pops up a box with all the lines found in the logs, but now I want to 'go to' that location in the log file, so that I can see what happened before or after the specific line.

Is it possible?

Alternatively, is it possible to specify a number n to return +/- n lines above and below the found string rather than just the 1 line where the string was found?

Comment: I don't know anything about multitail, but you can try `grep -A<n> -B<n> "search pattern" path/to/logfile`, (where `<n>` is the `n` you mentioned in your last paragraph) and optionally pipe that to tail for further analysis.

Comment: Can't you use the vi command and hit '/<string>' ?